# XmlDeserialize -> not working after generated class from xsd.exe

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I have a XSD file and a XML file. I used XSD.exe to generate the c# class:

```
xsd.exe /c myxsd.xsd
```

I created a new console application doing the following:

```
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(pain00100101));

        string filename = "test.xml";
        Stream s = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
        var myFoo = ser.Deserialize(s);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

I get the following exception:

```
There is an error in XML document (2, 2).
```

The inner exception says:

```
{"<Document xmlns='urn:iso:std:iso:20022:xsd:pain.001.001.01'> was not expected."}
```

I validated my XML against the XSD and it's valid....

You can download the XML from

http://www.iso20022.org/documents/obsolete/XML_instance_pain.001.001.01.zip

and the XSD from

http://www.iso20022.org/documents/obsolete/XML_schema_pain.001.001.01.zip

Comment: Seems that your XML is not starting with `<xml>` declaration. Is it so?

Comment: No it is not so... You can download the XML file from the link in the post...